# Package version conflict when building network-manager-applet ubuntu package from source

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, dependencies, xfce

I am using xubuntu 18.04, which has an XFCE user interface that uses several GNOME widgets, notably network-manager. network-manager has some limitations such as the lack of a way to prioritize networks via drag-and-drop. I'm aware of CLI ways to do it but would like to contribute this feature to the GUI, so I'm attempting to compile `network-manager-applet` from source in preparation to contribute code to it.

My system packages have been updated with `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`.

If I type:

```
apt-get source network-manager-applet --compile
```

I get:

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: error: Unmet build dependencies: dh-translations gnome-common libnm-util-dev (>= 1.8) libnm-glib-dev (>= 1.8) libnm-glib-vpn-dev (>= 1.8) network-manager-dev (>= 1.8) libnm-dev (>= 1.8) libmm-glib-dev libjansson-dev (>= 2.7) libselinux-dev libappindicator3-dev libdbusmenu-gtk3-dev (>= 16.04) libgcr-3-dev (>= 3.14) libgck-1-dev (>= 3.14) libgirepository1.0-dev gobject-introspection gtk-doc-tools libgtk-3-doc libglib2.0-doc
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: build dependencies/conflicts unsatisfied; aborting
dpkg-buildpackage: warning: (Use -d flag to override.)
E: Build command 'cd network-manager-applet-1.8.10 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed.
```

OK, fair enough, so I looked up how to fetch the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep network-manager-applet
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:network-manager-applet : Depends: libnm-dev (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

OK, so let's try to install `libnm-dev`:

```
boutell@roxnsox:~/xubuntu$ sudo apt-get install libnm-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnm-dev : Depends: libnm0 (= 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1) but 1.10.14-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Note that I have no held packages:

```
boutell@roxnsox:~/xubuntu$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
boutell@roxnsox:~/xubuntu$
```

How do I resolve the conflict with `libnm0` in order to move forward?

(I'm aware I will eventually have to leave off `--compile` and cd into the source folder and build myself to work on the code, but I wind up in the same place in that scenario. The above series of steps should be good for purposes of resolving this issue.)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
libnm-dev : Depends: libnm0 (= 1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1) but 1.10.14-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

Suggests you have a newer version of libnm0 than is compatible with the libnm-dev that you have available; it's slightly mis-worded, I think.

```
sudo apt purge libnm0 && sudo apt install libnm-dev
```

Will remove your libnm0 version and do your install by specifying libnm-dev, which will pull in the dependencies it needs.

Post back if you're still getting dependency errors.

FWIW **`aptitude` will search for alternative resolutions to dependency issues**. So, in your case, in interactive mode (`sudo aptitude`) when you specify "install libnm-dev" (by clicking <kbd>+</kbd> against the appropriate entry; search is <kbd>/</kbd> then type your keyword) it will say somethings broken and offer you to press <kbd>e</kbd> and then you can use <kbd>,</kbd>/<kbd>.</kbd> to work through a list of solutions.

You can **use `aptitude` like `apt` in a terminal too**:
    sudo aptitude install libnm-dev

and again, it should offer various solutions to resolve the dependency problem.

Another alternative is to **directly specify the version of libnm0** that libnm-dev wants:

```
sudo apt install libnm0=1.10.6-2ubuntu1.1
```

but that only works if that version is in your repos (specified in /etc/apt/sources.list &c.).

Comment: Thanks, I went with the aptitude suggestion. The first "solution" it offered was to... not do it. But building on your advice I hit "." to see another solution, and the second solution rolled back libnm0 to a compatible version, which made sense to me as I wouldn't be left without it even temporarily. After that I was able to build-deps and compile.