# Ubuntu 20.04 won't load after reinstalling libnm0

Tags: networking, 20.04, nvidia, gnome, package-management

Network manager has been a little buggy for a while. [I found the solution here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185188/gnome-control-center-crash-when-clicking-on-wifi-gear-network-settings) and i ran `sudo apt install network-manager-gnome`, which threw an error about nvidia public key. I solved it by following [the steps here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/notice-cuda-linux-repository-key-rotation/212772)

However, i tried running the above command again, but i got:

```
network-manager-gnome : Depends: libnma0 (= 1.8.24-1ubuntu2) but 1.8.24-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
```

[I found this solution here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1151711/package-version-conflict-when-building-network-manager-applet-ubuntu-package-fro), and executed the first line which was said to be dangerous but i saw the warning too late

Once i did so, `libnm0` was uninstalled bit the second command wasn't executed because network manager stopped working. After reboot, ubuntu doesn't work anymore and is showing me this message after grub window:

```
/dev/nume0n1p6: recovering journal
/dev/nume0n1p6: clean ..../... files, .../... blocks
[6.294993] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\DPPP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20201113/psargs-330)
[6.295030] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM.IDSP due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psargs-529)
[6.295055] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20201113/psargs-529)
```

I only have ubuntu 20.04 installed in PC. I can reach grub and it's terminal screen but i cant use apt install there

So, how can i reboot into my PC again?

Comment: You probably don't have `Ubuntu Core 20` installed on your machine, do you have `Ubuntu 20.04` or `Ubuntu 20.10` or something else? Those are all different OSes, and there is no such thing as "Ubuntu 20"

Comment: @Esther I have ubuntu 20.04

Comment: then [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1411908/edit) your question to correct that information.

Comment: @Esther i edited it. Now how to solve the problem?

Comment: You can try booting into a live USB and chrooting into your existing install to install network-manager-gnome there. You will have a network connection from the live USB that way

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try